# Calling each value of an array or csv as a parameter in a url

Tags: karate

I am new to karate and read through most of the examples, but can't quite crack this. Your help is much appreciated! Assuming I have an array and I need to call a service and pass each value of this as a param, how do I do that please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given url 'http://httpbin.org'
  And path 'get'
  And param foo = '<value>'
  When method get
  Then status 200

  Examples:
    | value |
    | hello |
    | world |
```

And in Karate 0.9.0 onwards you can do this:

```
Background:
  * def data = [{ value: 'hello' }, { value: 'world' }]

Scenario Outline:
  Given url 'http://httpbin.org'
  And path 'get'
  And param foo = '<value>'
  When method get
  Then status 200

  Examples:
    | data |
```

EDIT: and if you need to transform an existing primitive array:

```
Background:
  * def array = ['hello', 'world']
  * def data = karate.map(array, function(x){ return { value: x } })

Scenario Outline:
  Given url 'http://httpbin.org'
  And path 'get'
  And param foo = '<value>'
  When method get
  Then status 200

  Examples:
    | data |
```

Comment: It's not this this simple. My array has 86 values like:  * def listOfUrlNames = ["What-are-delivery-times-uk","Test-question-page","I-get-the-message-that-my-email-address-is-already-being-used-uk", etc] and the rest of the code :   When path 'knowledgeArticles', <url>
    And header Authorization = "Bearer "+token
    And header ACCEPT = 'text/html'
    And header Accept-Language = 'en-US'
    And path 'get'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Examples:
      |url  |
      | listOfUrlNames |

Comment: @DeepthiRavindra I thought you read the docs ;) edited my answer. there is something like `karate.map(array, function)`

Comment: Yes, but how to pass it as param to another url ? it has to execute 86 times with same api but different parameters

Comment: Yes each of the value in the array listOfUrlNames should be passed as a parameter to another url. So it should be doing a GET 86 times with each of the values in the array

Comment: Sorry, I think it is not clear.. I have an array like this: * def listOfUrlNames = ["What-are-delivery-times-uk","Test-question-page","I-get-the-message-that-my-email-address-is-already-being-used-uk", etc] and it has 86  strings in it. I need to pass each string into another url. How do I do that?

Comment: @DeepthiRavindra can you please do one thing first. paste the answer I provided into a fresh `Feature`. see if it works or not. then ask questions. deal ? hint: there are already 2 params in the answer. did you expect me to put 86 values !?

Comment: Sorry, I tried the above.  It did work. It was so quick. I wonder whether it has executed 86 times. I want to print the url including the param it is executing each time it does a GET. How do I do that? Thank you so much for your patience ! :)

Comment: `* def listOfUrlNames = ["What-are-Vikings-delivery-times-uk","Test-question-page","I-get-the-message-that-my-email-address-is-already-being-used-uk","Can-I"] \n
    * match response.articles[*].urlName contains listOfUrlNames
    * def values = read('classpath:faqs.csv')
    * def data = karate.map(values, function(x){ return { value: x } })
    * print data
    When path 'knowledgeArticles', data
    And header Authorization = "Bearer "+token
    And header ACCEPT = 'text/html'
    And header Accept-Language = 'en-US'
    And path 'get'
    Then status 200`

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried the code above, it is not adding the param to the url for some reason.. it is executing 86 times, but without the param

Comment: @DeepthiRavindra sorry all I can do is point you to this now, or hope someone else has more patience: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for all the help and your patience :)